# uWSGI: can't unpickle with a namedtuple - "can't get attribute" error?

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

I have a Flask service that runs perfectly by itself with the default Flask web server. I'm trying to host it with uWSGI, but in that environment, I'm running into issues where I'm not able to access some required data in a pickle.

This is my main WSGI script:

```
from collections import namedtuple
from search_service import app

SomeNamedTuple = namedtuple('SomeNamedTuple ', 'idx data')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

And in my Flask service, I'm doing something like this:

```
unpickled_data = None

@app.before_first_request
def startup():
    global unpickled_data

    with open('data.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
        unpickled_data = pickle.load(handle)
```

No matter how I try to define the namedtuple (in wsgi.py, in my Flask API, etc...), I end up get this error:

```
[2017-12-09 19:40:57,209] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ringham/app/appenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ringham/app/appenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1607, in full_dispatch_request
    self.try_trigger_before_first_request_functions()
  File "/home/ringham/app/appenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1654, in try_trigger_before_fi
rst_request_functions
    func()
  File "./service.py", line 44, in startup
    min_eval_data = pickle.load(handle)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'SomeNamedTuple ' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

What might I be missing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but I had a similar problem with pickling a named tuple, in that I'm making a game and have a separate level designer program that uses a named tuple to store the data for each cell on the grid. Without going into too much detail about my program, I basically had to declare the named tuple in the global scope in my game for the level data to load properly.

At first I was declaring the named tuple within the `main()` function, but it wouldn't `pickle.load` my level data without throwing an `AttributeError`, but when I moved the named tuple declaration outside of `main()` into the global scope, the level data loaded fine. I still can't figure out why. Maybe named tuples need to be declared globally? It is global in my level designer.

I don't know anything about Flask, but try declaring `SomeNamedTuple = namedtuple('SomeNamedTuple ', 'idx data')` in the global scope of your Flask service.